# How to add more values with filter

Tags: java, android, filter

I've got a filter and I can put there only one value which matches completely 100%, but I would like to add more than one match.

How can I do that?

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
    FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
    if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
        ArrayList<Country> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Country>();

        for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++) {
            Country country = originalList.get(i);

            while(constraint.toString().toLowerCase().matches(
                        country.getRegion().toString().toLowerCase()))
                filteredItems.add(country);
        }
        result.count = filteredItems.size();
        result.values = filteredItems;
    } else {
        synchronized(this) {
            result.values = originalList;
            result.count = originalList.size();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
String[] values = constraint.toString().split(",");
```

And use comma or other symbol for separate your values.

> ```
> @Override
>     protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
>
>         constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
>         FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
>         if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
>         {
>             String[] values = constraint.toString().split(",");
>             ArrayList<Country> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Country>();
>
>             for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++)
>             {
>                 Country country = originalList.get(i);
>                 for (int j = 0; i<values.lenght(); j++) {
>                     while(values[j].toString().toLowerCase().matches(country.getRegion().toString().toLowerCase()))
>                         filteredItems.add(country);
>                 }
>             }
>             result.count = filteredItems.size();
>             result.values = filteredItems;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             synchronized(this)
>             {
>                 result.values = originalList;
>                 result.count = originalList.size();
>             }
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

Comment: where I should add it?

Comment: I added this "for" in your code for (int j = 0; i<values.lenght(); j++) {}